# How to setup WinMerge to make it to ignore lines which are starting with "> Test"?

Tags: winmerge

I am looking for a way to setup WinMerge to allow me to compare two text files. BUt to make my comparison  easier, I would appreciate if this software could ignore the some lines, in function of how they are starting.

I tried to use the LinesFilter option, but I am little bit confused of about how to use this option.

Could you please help me ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official document](https://manual.winmerge.org/en/Filters.html#Filters_LineFilterSyntax):

> A line filter is a rule that is evaluated against each single-line difference in your compared files, if line filter rules are enabled. When a rule matches a single-line difference, the difference is ignored.

Your question is quite similar to the first example idea on the document. If you want to ignore the lines starting with `> Test`, you can use the following simple RegExp syntax:

```
^> Test
```

It will ignore the entire change in the line starting with `> Test`:

[image]

In case you want to ignore the spaces ahead `> Test`, just change the RegExp syntax to:

```
^\s*> Test
```

[image: include space]

Explain the RegExp syntax above (by [regex101](https://regex101.com)):

- `^` asserts position at start of a line
- `\s` matches any whitespace character (equivalent to `[\r\n\t\f\v ]`)
- `*` matches the previous token between **zero** and **unlimited** times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
- `> Test` matches the characters `> Test` literally (case sensitive)